# Plugging in a list of words into a phrase

Tags: american-english

I'm writing a sentence that uses a plugged list of words into my main phrase. I think I picked this up from reading stuff that used a similar construction(?) but I'm not sure if it's formally/academically correct. You may recognize what it is referring to.

> "Those with gold in their bodies are meant to be rulers; those with silver, auxiliaries; those with iron and bronze, craftsmen."

1) Is this correct/advised? (in AmE)
2) Does this thing have a name?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is still keeping you up at night, or for future reference, if you will:

1. Yes, your example is correct, and certainly appropriate in both AmE and BE.
2. The above is a case of what's known as a hierarchy of punctuation.

> In complex lists, semicolons are used to separate the list items
>   because commas are used within the list items themselves.

[>Source<](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_in_lists.htm)